# SubjectBehavior in my UserService and profile Component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, angular, rxjs

I have a ShareService :

```
 isLogin$:BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false); <==== default value is false
    CheckUser = this.isLogin$.asObservable();
    public isLogin (bool){
        this.isLogin$.next(bool);
}
```

and This is my Profile Component :

```
 _shareService.CheckUser.subscribe(val =>{

            this.isLogin = val;
            if(!val)
                _router.navigate(['AccessDenied']);

 });
```

and this is my authService :

```
  public authorize() {
        this._util.get('api/profile/my').then(value => {

                UserService._data = value.result;
                this._shareService.isLogin(true);

        }).catch(reason => {
  this._shareService.isLogin(false);
        });

    }
```

And When my App get running i execute my `authorize()` function...
so what is my problem ?!
when i refreshing the page on profile route my problem is i use `BehaviorSubject` with default value and until my `authorize()` function get Check  my `BehaviorSubject` send the false value in profile Component and redirect to `AccessDenied` page !
and i try `Subject()` but dont worked !
What should I do?
i can subscribe the `CheckUser` in `AccessDenied` Component and when value is true again redirect to the profile !but this is not good idea...i have same protected route...and when i refresh page in each protected page, redirect to the profile page !

Comment: What's the problem with `Subject` instead of `BehaviorSubject`?

Comment: when i get in profile route cant subscribe the value ! but whit `BehaviorSubject` it's ok ! i dont know why...

Comment: What do you mean by "can't subscribe the value"?

Comment: I apologize...cant subscribe the `CheckUser`. it seems like value Is not sent...

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work. You should be able to subscribe `CheckUser` the same no matter if it is a `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject`. `Subject` just doesn't emit a value unless you call `_shareService.isLogin()`

Comment: when i use `Subject` and From another route get to profile route...value Is not sent...and isLogin in profile Component is false !

Comment: Hard to tell what's going on. Maybe a Plunker to reproduce could help.

Comment: It takes 333 days :D

Comment: I can't help you by looking at a few fragments of your code (and I don't want to investigate a whole project - in case you might ask to look at a GitHub repo).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `BehaviorSubject` to have your last value available to new subscribers, you might want to consider using `ReplaySubject`:

```
isLogin$:Subject<boolean> = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1); <==== default value is false
    CheckUser = this.isLogin$.asObservable();
    public isLogin (bool){
        this.isLogin$.next(bool);
}
```

If I understand your description correctly this should work. One one hand, you won't have a `false` value waiting there, on the other, late subscriber (as part of routing actions) will still see the last value.